# Run cassandra-stress get Not enough replica available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE in 3 node of datastax-enterprise

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

in datastax-enterprise 
cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.12.1046 | DSE 4.8.4 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3

when run cassandra-stress, get error below:

```
[root@pg0 ~]# cassandra-stress write n=19000000 -rate threads=100 -node 192.168.35.150
Unable to create stress keyspace: Keyspace names must be case-insensitively unique ("keyspace1" conflicts with "keyspace1")
Sleeping 2s...
Warming up WRITE with 50000 iterations...
WARN  04:12:00 Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, but epoll is not available. Using NIO instead.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll4216253360502585010.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll4216253360502585010.so)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:193) ~[netty-all-4.0.33.dse.jar:4.0.33.dse]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:48) ~[netty-all-4.0.33.dse.jar:4.0.33.dse]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:32) ~[netty-all-4.0.33.dse.jar:4.0.33.dse]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil.<clinit>(NettyUtil.java:68) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyOptions.eventLoopGroup(NettyOptions.java:101) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.<init>(Connection.java:695) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1286) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:339) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.util.JavaDriverClient.connect(JavaDriverClient.java:117) [stress.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.getJavaDriverClient(StressSettings.java:189) [stress.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.getJavaDriverClient(StressSettings.java:171) [stress.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.SettingsNode.resolveAllPermitted(SettingsNode.java:80) [stress.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressMetrics.<init>(StressMetrics.java:62) [stress.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction.run(StressAction.java:198) [stress.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction.warmup(StressAction.java:105) [stress.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction.run(StressAction.java:61) [stress.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress.main(Stress.java:109) [stress.jar:na]
Connected to cluster: fullstack
Datatacenter: Cassandra; Host: /192.168.35.150; Rack: rack1
Datatacenter: Cassandra; Host: /192.168.35.151; Rack: rack1
Datatacenter: Cassandra; Host: /192.168.35.152; Rack: rack1
Failed to connect over JMX; not collecting these stats
Running WRITE with 100 threads for 19000000 iteration
Failed to connect over JMX; not collecting these stats
type,      total ops,    op/s,    pk/s,   row/s,    mean,     med,     .95,         .99,    .999,     max,   time,   stderr, errors,  gc: #,  max ms,  sum ms,  sdv ms,      mb
total,          4914,    1443,    1443,    1443,    59.4,     4.1,    13.4,      3181.9,  3241.9,  3243.4,    3.4,  0.00000,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
total,         17349,   12167,   12167,   12167,    12.2,     5.4,    24.3,    35.9,  3174.5,  3192.0,    4.4,  0.55715,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0
```

last show error below:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)
total,       5711242,    3527,    3527,    3527,     1.1,     1.0,     1.7,     2.5,     6.5,     9.2, 1499.2,  0.00563,      0,      0,       0,       0,       0,       0

java.io.IOException: Operation x10 on key(s) [4b314b4c3537364f4e30]: Error executing: (UnavailableException): Not enough replica available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)

    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.error(Operation.java:216)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.timeWithRetry(Operation.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:99)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:259)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction$Consumer.run(StressAction.java:309)
java.io.IOException: Operation x10 on key(s) [3339304c503338363630]: Error executing: (UnavailableException): Not enough replica available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)

    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.error(Operation.java:216)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.timeWithRetry(Operation.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:99)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:259)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction$Consumer.run(StressAction.java:309)
java.io.IOException: Operation x10 on key(s) [3635393236394c4d3531]: Error executing: (UnavailableException): Not enough replica available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)

    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.error(Operation.java:216)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.timeWithRetry(Operation.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:99)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:259)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction$Consumer.run(StressAction.java:309)
java.io.IOException: Operation x10 on key(s) [384c31503530394e3131]: Error executing: (UnavailableException): Not enough replica available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)

    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.error(Operation.java:216)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.timeWithRetry(Operation.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:99)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:259)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction$Consumer.run(StressAction.java:309)
FAILURE
```

is there any problem?
the command is : cassandra-stress write n=19000000 -rate threads=4 -node 192.168.35.150

3 nodes

Comment: any update? I came across same error.

Comment: I also have the same error..any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please desc the keyspace. 
What is the strategy type and the Replication Factor.

Please note, if your RF = 1 then there is only one copy of the data in your cluster.

Comment: this is actually a legit comment, the keyspace1 is setup as RF=1. why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

pls check your consistency level of cassandra.

`# cqlsh <ip adress> -e "CONSISTENCY;"`

And specify the confirmed setting with the "cl=<consistency level>" option.

`# cassandra-stress write n=19000000 cl=<consistency level> -rate threads=100 -node 192.168.35.150`

This solved the problem for me.